# When a Task is created or updated, extract URL from description and copy to a custom field?

Tags: trigger, process-builder

An external tool is creating/updating Task objects which contain a URL (the pattern is consistent e.g. https://app.tool.com/xyz).

When that happens, we want to trigger an update to a custom field on the Task with that exact URL.

Is this possible? It does not seem so with Process Builder but was hoping for another way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as a trigger, you can write:

```
trigger triggerName on Task (before insert, before update) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile('https?://\\S+');
  for(Task record: Trigger.new) {
    if(record.Description != null) {
      Matcher m = p.matcher(record.Description);
      if(m.find()) {
        record.Link_URL__c = m.group(0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can adjust the pattern as you like. The current pattern looks for a http:// or https:// that stops at the first space (e.g. `https://my.api.com/path for information` would extract `https://my.api.com/path`).